# Number of elements in a group ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $R$ be the group ring $\mathbb{Z}_5 S_3$, where $S_3$ is a symmetric group.

I need to calculate the number of elements in the group ring, and I'm not sure how to do it, is it just $5^3 = 125$?

Comment: Where did the $3$ come from?  How many elements does $S_3$ have?

Comment: My mistake, there are 6 elements in $S_3$, so are there $5^6$ elements?

Comment: How are you defining the group ring?

Comment: All the question asks is to state the number of elements in the group ring $\mathbb{Z}_5 S_3$ - I'm not sure how it's defined

Comment: You are definitely asking the wrong question!

Comment: Am I?
I'm not sure what the right question to ask is then...

Comment: The right question would be "What is the definition of a group ring?"

Comment: I have found something that says the for a group G and a ring R, the group ring RG is defined as ${a_1g1 + ... + a_kg_k \  , a_1,...,a_k \in R, g_1,...,g_k \in G}$

Answer (score 1):

There's not as many as you might think. Each element of $\Bbb Z_5[S_3]$ can be thought of a "formal $\Bbb Z_5$-linear combination" of elements of $S_3$. You have six "terms" in every such combination (some terms may have a zero coefficient), and five choices for the coefficient of every term.